# MyBatis integration with JBoss 7.1 web application

Tags: jboss, java-ee-6, cdi, mybatis

Had anybody attempted to use MyBatis as their persistence library for a JBoss 7.1 /Java EE6 application?

I'm wondering what are the best approaches to handling connections, transations, rollbacks etc?

How about CDI support? Looking around online it seems at this time MyBatis only supports two Dependency Injection (JSR-330) frameworks, Google Guice and Spring. I did run into CDI Extensions which may be something look into.

My idea would be to have the container handle all of the above however it may be difficult getting to that point.

Any tips, hints, experiences?

Comment: Should you have decided to implement it yourself, it would be great if you could sketch your solution here...

Comment: Yes.. I will be working on implementing this solution in a few months. I will use this entry and comment everything I discover with the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new mybatis-cdi module. It is not released yet, but you can try the snapshot, it is at github: https://github.com/mybatis/cdi

Comment: Our current implementation of how we handle this is very flawed, error prone, and very difficult to handle transactions appropriately. Looking at your code, it looks much cleaner... So far two thumbs up..

Answer (score 1):

There is no CDI support at all but as you said, if you want DI go Spring or Guice.

With JBoss you have mainly two chances:
- EJB 3
- Spring

If using EJB 3 transactions are handled automatically by them. MyBatis just ignores transactions and lets the container commit/rollback.

When using Spring, MyBatis ties to Spring transactions using the integration module MyBatis-Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I would create my own CDI bean - use `@Produces` for a factory, and `@Inject` to get the session.

Here is old iBatis Spring factory, that might be the producer, after some changes:
[SqlMapClientFactoryBean](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/orm/ibatis/SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java.html)

Comment: I may end up doing something very similar to this.. Thank you

Comment: I am actually now working on the same concept. It will be a JBoss AS 7 quickstart. I'll post here what I will end up with.

Comment: I think you could annotate methods dealing with MyBatis with arbitraty qualifier; then intercept these calls and open the session before invocation. I've used this once for Weld-SE + Hibernate, need to find.

Comment: Until then - https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MyBatisIBatisAndJBossAS7?prevContainerType=2020  Feel free to comment.

Comment: Similar principle as works with \@Resource UserTransaction could be used - thread local proxy which would be updated based on intercepting methods annotated, e.g., \@MyBatisTransaction, or such.